# Variable output to workspace with correct function call in command window-fixed-

Tags: matlab

1. I have function____function [a,b,c,d] = master_function(fname, path)
2. In command window I proceed to type,

   ```
   fname = '';
   path = '';
   [a,b,c,d] = master_function(fname, path);
   ```
3. I pick a file. Code is successfully completed.
4. a,b,c,d do not show up in the workspace
5. I remove the semicolons from the specified line in the code pertaining to each variable. Then when I run the function again, all values to the variables appear in the command window. So they are there but somehow Matlab is refusing to store them in the workspace?

Comment: the `function` keyword doesn't call the function, it defines it.

Comment: This is MATLAB 101.  Please read a proper tutorial before asking questions here.

Comment: I corrected my mistake in my question. And apparently it isn't. I have created a massive list of functions and complete programs calling functions. This is only one that refuses to show my variables for some very strange unheard of reason. But there is no reason to be rude. Create functions in matlab is matlab 101 which I know how to do after my training with Mathworks

Comment: What happens if you remove the semicolon from your call to master_function?

Comment: Except this isn't a thing: `for some very strange unheard of reason`. MATLAB isn't some sentient black box, it is performing the instructions that *you* gave it. There is absolutely no way to help you without a **functioning** example and I can almost guarantee it's a simple typographical error.